# Calculating closest distance between coordinates in two dataframes in R

Tags: r

I have two dataframes one for people locations (df1) and the other for housing locations (df2)

```
df1<-structure(list(Persons = c(1,2,3,4), 
                     Latitude = c(-23.8, -23.8, -23.9, -23.9), 
                     Longitude = c(-49.6, -49.3, -49.4, -49.8),Sex = c("M","F","M","F"), 
                     Age = c(22, 44, 32, 86)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2<-structure(list(House = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), Latitude = c(-23.4, -23.7, -23.4, -23.8,-23.8, -23.9, -23.2, -23.7), 
                     Longitude = c(-49.7, -49.4, -49.6, -49.7,-49.9, -49.7, -49.5, -49.8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

I simply want to get the which house is closest to each person and get the distance in feet added to that dataframe. I tried `distGeo` but it did the opposite (which person is closest to each house) and I did not trust binding it back since both dataframes have different observations.

Comment: Please show the code you used.

Comment: @dcarlson ```distance_b <-distGeo(df1[, c("Longitude ", "Latitude ")], df2[, c("Longitude ", "Latitude ")])/3.28084```  It just ends up doing all of the observations on df2. I just want it to just have the observations and dataframe of df1 with the closest coordinate of df2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
library(sf)
library(nngeo)
df1 <- st_as_sf(df1, coords = c('Longitude', 'Latitude'), crs = 4326)
df2 <- st_as_sf(df2, coords = c('Longitude', 'Latitude'), crs = 4326)
# k = 1 for finding 1 nearest neighbor
dfjoin <- nngeo::st_nn(df1, df2, k = 1, returnDist = T)
```

This return you list of 2 with the nearest House and the second list containing  distance in meter

```
df1$house <- dfjoin[[1]]
df1$dist <- dfjoin[[2]]
```

Comment: This is helpful thank you! It joins correctly and the distance seems fine but weirdly when I try to arrange the distance on view, I get this error even though it joined fine. ```Error in rank(x, ties.method = "min", na.last = "keep") : 
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'greater```

Comment: The column  is a list `class(df1$dist)` so do this `df1$dist <- unlist(df1$list)` . Do this for house column as well if needed.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I am just really bad when it comes to working with sf classes and going back to data frame. By the way it should be ```unlist(df1$dist) right instead of list?

Comment: Yes I meant `unlist(df1$dist)`

Comment: I tried to find the distance from df1 (persons) not only to df2(houses) but to df3 (for example zoos). However, when running `dfjoin <- nngeo::st_nn(df1, df2, df3, k = 1, returnDist = T)`  I get this error `Error in Ops.sfc(left) : argument "e2" is missing, with no default`

Comment: ```st_nn(
  x,
  y,
  sparse = TRUE,
  k = 1,
  maxdist = Inf,
  returnDist = FALSE,
  progress = TRUE,
  parallel = 1
)``` , I think you can do it for two at a time. Look at ```?nngeo::st_nn``` it has just x and y.

Answer (score 0):

One naive approach would be the following

```
# create output matrix outside of loops, fill with NA
pairwise_distance <- matrix(NA, nrow(df1), nrow(df2))

# loop through both dfs
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  for (j in 1:nrow(df2)){
  pairwise_distance[i, j] <- geosphere::distGeo(
    c(df1[i, "Latitude"], df1[i,"Longitude"]), 
    c(df2[j, "Latitude"], df2[j,"Longitude"])) 
  }
}
# for each row
# attach the column index of the distance matrix 
# (correspondens to house index in df2) with the 
# minimum value to df1 as new variable `nearest_house_id` 
df1$nearest_house_id <- apply(pairwise_distance, 1, which.min)
# also attach corresponding (minimum) distance
df1$nearest_house_distance <- apply(pairwise_distance, 1, min)
# Hope you want it this way around.
```

Please consider this answer as first input only. Probably, it needs to be adjusted to missing values or unique matching or sth like that. In addition, it is quite verbose.